# Set up 2 log files with log4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log4r

I have added log4r in my Rails 2.3.8 project. I want to create 2 log files.

1. For application login (INFO messages) (application.log)
2. Error messages (any message other than info message) (errors.log)

Following are my yml configuration files for each logger

```
error_config.yml (errors.log)

# *** YAML2LOG4R ***
error_config:
  # define all pre config ...
  pre_config:
    custom_levels:
      - DEBUG
      - INF
      - PRT
      - WRN
      - ERR
      - FAT
    global:
      level: DEBUG
    root  :
      level: DEBUG
    parameters:
      - name   : x
        value  : aaa
      - name   : y
        value  : bbb

  # define all loggers ...
  loggers:
    - name      : mylogger
      level     : DEBUG
      additive  : 'false'
      trace     : 'false'
      outputters:
        - stderr
        - logfile

  # define all outputters (incl. formatters)
  outputters:
    - type     : StderrOutputter
      name     : stderr 
      level    : DEBUG
      only_at  :
        - INF
        - WRN
        - FAT
      formatter:
        date_pattern: '%y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
        pattern     : '%d %l: %m '
        type        : PatternFormatter

    - type        : DateFileOutputter
      name        : logfile
      level       : DEBUG
      date_pattern: '%Y%m%d'
      trunc       : 'false'
      dirname     : "/home/sameera/workspace/project/log"
      filename    : "errors.log"
      formatter   :
        date_pattern: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        pattern     : '%d %l - %m'
        type        : PatternFormatter
```

---

```
application_config.yml (application.log)

# *** YAML2LOG4R ***
application_config:
  # define all pre config ...
  pre_config:
    custom_levels:
      - DEBUG
      - INF
      - PRT
      - WRN
      - ERR
      - FAT
    global:
      level: DEBUG
    root  :
      level: DEBUG
    parameters:
      - name   : x
        value  : aaa
      - name   : y
        value  : bbb

  # define all loggers ...
  loggers:
    - name      : application
      level     : DEBUG
      additive  : 'false'
      trace     : 'false'
      outputters:
        - stderr
        - logfile

  # define all outputters (incl. formatters)
  outputters:
    - type     : StderrOutputter
      name     : stderr 
      level    : DEBUG
      only_at  :
        - INF
        - WRN
        - FAT
      formatter:
        date_pattern: '%y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
        pattern     : '%d %l: %m '
        type        : PatternFormatter

    - type        : DateFileOutputter
      name        : application
      level       : DEBUG
      date_pattern: '%Y%m%d'
      trunc       : 'false'
      dirname     : "/home/sameera/workspace/project/log"
      filename    : "application.log"
      formatter   :
        date_pattern: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        pattern     : '%d %l - %m'
        type        : PatternFormatter
```

and following is the code to initialize both the loggers

```
h = YAML.load(File.open("config/error_config.yml"))
app_log = YAML.load(File.open("config/application_config.yml"))

log_cfg = YamlConfigurator
log_cfg['TEST'] = 'foobar'
log_cfg.decode_yaml h['error_config']



applog_cfg = YamlConfigurator
applog_cfg['TEST'] = 'foobar'
applog_cfg.decode_yaml app_log['application_config']


$ERRORLOG = Log4r::Logger['error_config']
$APPLICATION = Log4r::Logger['application_config']


$ERRORLOG.debug "info message"
$APPLICATION.debug "info message"
```

This code works fine, but it print both the messages in the errors.log (where as I want the second message to be print on the application.log).

Is there any simple way of having 2 logs files through one log4r instance?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your "error_config.yml" file defines the output level as "debug".

```
loggers:
  - name      : mylogger
    level     : DEBUG
```

maybe you want it to be "WARN" ?

```
loggers:
  - name      : mylogger
    level     : WARN
```

p.s. ^_^ naming convension is important. please be friendly to the readers of your code. (usually is yourself). which is more clearer?

```
h = YAML.load(File.open("config/error_config.yml"))
error_config = YAML.load(File.open("config/error_config.yml"))
```